# php_oci8 not loading on wamp server 2.0?

Tags: php, wamp, oracle-call-interface

I enabled the extension on wamp ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7uKG.gif)) but I still get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\wamp\www\wp1\wp-content\plugins\hrf\tmp.php on line 4
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall WAMP, Install ZendServer Community edition.

Maybe it is not a right answer for your question, but it definitely works.

ZendServer is most stable PHP stack.

But if you want to keep WAMP, try this:

make sure you have enabled

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

in your php.ini file (or any included ini file)
Best option is run

```
phpinfo()
```

It will tel you all you need to know.

Next thing to note is that php_oci8.dll has dependancy on other DLLs,
on my installation it reference oci.dll from OracleInstant Client.

Comment: Thank you. Installing Oracle Instant Client solved the issue.

Comment: @AlGallaf, I have installed Oracle Instant Client but I am facing the same problem. how does you overcome this problem.